# ReactiveUI - this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, reactiveui

I download latest ReactiveUI (5.0.2) via nuget to my project based on .NET 4.5.

I created simple view model class with one property:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using ReactiveUI.Xaml;

    namespace ReactiveUI.Study.ViewModels
    {
        public class ShellViewModel : ReactiveObject
        {
            #region Properties

            private string _login;

            public string Login
            {
                get
                {
                    return _login;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.Login, value);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

When I tried compile my project I get exception

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ref string' because it is not a delegate type
```

I just start learn I am not sure where is root of this problem because I use sample from
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/master/ReactiveUI_4Only.Samples.sln

and all projects are based on .NET 4.0 and also use older version of ReactiveUI.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _login, value);`?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange that's the answer - that from 5 that construct is the only version - post it so you can get your due upvote

Comment: @Murph Yeah one of my colleagues had this issue while ago while he was  refactoring some code. I just thought it looked familiar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.Login, value);
```

To

```
this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _login, value);
```

This is now the only way to declare properties as per the release notes:

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/docs/migrating-from-rxui4.md